# I'm calculating exterior derivatives and my answer is off by a factor of -1. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

For example. I want to find the exterior derivative of

$$\omega=(-3x-2y-z)dx +(2x^2+3y^3+4z^4)dy + (x+2y+3z)dz$$

Here's what I did:

$$ \begin{align} 
d\omega &= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-3x-2y-z)\ dx+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x^2+3y^3+4z^4)\ dy+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+2y+3z)\ dz\right]dx \\
&+ \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-3x-2y-z)\ dx+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2x^2+3y^3+4z^4)\ dy+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+2y+3z)\ dz\right]dy \\
&+ \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(-3x-2y-z)\ dx+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(2x^2+3y^3+4z^4)\ dy+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(x+2y+3z)\ dz\right]dz \\
&= (-3\ dx +4x\ dy +1\ dz)\ dx +(-2\ dx+9y^2\ dy+2\ dz)\ dy+(-1\ dx+16z^3\ dy+3\ dz)\ dz \\
&= 4x\ dy\ dx+ dz\ dx-2\ dx\ dy+2\ dz\ dy-1\ dx\ dz+16z^3\ dy\ dz \\
&= -4x\ dx\ dy-2\ dx\ dy-1\ dx\ dz-1\ dx\ dz-2\ dy\ dz+16z^3\ dy\ dz \\
&= (-4x-2)\ dx\ dy-2\ dx\ dz+(16z^3-2)\ dy\ dz
\end{align} $$

However, Maple says this:[image]

Maple says I'm off by a factor of -1? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: the derivative of $2x^2$ is $4x\,dx$, not $-2\,dx.$ The derivative of $4z^4$ is $16z^3\,dz,$ not $2\,dz.$

Comment: The derivative of $x$ is $+1$, not $-1$ times $dx.$ The derivative of $2y$ is $2\,dy,$ not $16z^3\,dy$ (???)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing things completely wrong, but I edited in a step with partial derivatives to show what I was doing.

Comment: Still don't see how you go from $2x^2$ to $-2\,dx.$

Comment: @ziggurism $2x^2\ dy$ becomes $4x\ dy\ dx$ in the first term of OP's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of operations is wrong. If 
$$ \omega = u\ dx + v\ dy + w\ dz $$

then
$$ \begin{align} 
d\omega &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \ dx\wedge dx + \frac{\partial v}{\ \partial x} \ dx \wedge dy + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\ dx \wedge dz \\
&\ + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \ dy\wedge dx + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \ dy \wedge dy + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\ dy \wedge dz \\
&\ + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \ dz\wedge dx + \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} \ dz \wedge dy + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\ dz \wedge dz
\end{align}
$$

You had it written as
$$ d\omega = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \ dx + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \ dy + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \ dz \right) \wedge dx + \dots $$

which caused the sign error

Comment: Aah, so simple! Thank you